# NativeScript and iOS Dynamic Framework with XIBs

Tags: ios, nativescript

My team has developed an [iOS library for drawing charts](http://www.scichart.com/ios-chart-examples). This library is 100% implemented in Objective C and is compiled as a Dynamic Framework.

We want to create a proof of concept app to show how to consume this within [NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/).

I have read, digested and understood [How to use Native Libraries with NativeScript](https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/ios/how-to/Use-Native-Libraries). All looks good :)

Then I discover that the iOS Dynamic Framework, which contains XIBs, cannot be loaded in NativeScript.

Is there any example of consuming a third party iOS Library which includes Xibs? Or is this simply not possible, and we must re-work the iOS library without the use of XIBs?

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. Wrap your framework in [NativeScript plugin](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/plugins).
2. Add the plugin to the app: `tns plugin add ./path/to/plugin/folder`
3. Consume the xib:

   ```
   var frameworkBundle = NSBundle.bundleForClass(SomeClassFromTheFramework.class);
   frameworkBundle.loadNibNamedOwnerOptions("MyXib", owner, null);
   ```

Let me know if you encounter any errors/issues?

Comment: You sir, are a hero. We're going to try this.